# Bezier curve trail generation animated

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbEEzE

```
<button class="move-me">Start animation</button>
<div class="circle">/div>

.circle {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background-color: #EBC84E;
border-radius: 100%;
margin-top:50px;
}  

$('.move-me').on('click', function() {
TweenMax.to(".circle", 2, {bezier:{curviness:2, type:"thru", values:[{x:0, y:0},{x:122, y:120},{x:239, y:0},{x:300, y:0},{x:411, y:120},{x:533, y:0}]}, ease:Linear.easeNone });
});
```

In this codepen I make the circle go from point A to point B. What I am trying to do is make the circle generate a line behind it so in the end I have the bezier curve that I specified drawn on the page.

Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Add `position: absolute;` in your css rule for `.circle` object.
- Store a reference to `$('.circle')` object in a variable named say `circleObject` and then use that in `TweenMax.to()` call.
- In your `TweenMax.to()` call, add an `onUpdate` callback along with
  `onUpdateParams` and `onUpdateScope` with values being `onAnimationUpdate`, `[circleObject]` and `this` respectively.
- Create a function named `onAnimationUpdate` with parameter to be received by the name, say `circle` like so: `function onAnimationUpdate(circle){...}`.
- Add `$(circle).clone().appendTo(document.body);` line inside this newly created function.

Here is the code in full:

***CSS:***

```
.circle {
    position: absolute; // <-- added this line
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #EBC84E;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

***JavaScript:***

```
var circleObject = $('.circle'); // moved '.circle' here so it can be passed as a parameter later on to the 'onUpdate' callback

$('.move-me').on('click', function () {
    TweenMax.to(circleObject, 2, {
        bezier: {
            curviness: 2,
            type: 'thru',
            values: [
                {x:0, y:0},
                {x:122, y:120},
                {x:239, y:0},
                {x:300, y:0},
                {x:411, y:120},
                {x:533, y:0}
            ]
        },
        onUpdate: onAnimationUpdate, // <-- added this line
        onUpdateScope: this, // <-- added this line
        onUpdateParams: circleObject, // <-- added this line. Read more about these here: [http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/].
        ease: Linear.easeNone
    });
});

function onAnimationUpdate(circle){ // <-- added this function block
    $(circle).clone().appendTo(document.body); // <-- and of course, added this. This line creates a clone of your '.circle' object and places it exactly where your '.circle' object currently is i.e. cloning.
}
```

Hope this helps. Here is a working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/u90yz86r/)**.

P.S. There is one thing that needs to be said here. If you are looking to *draw* stuff on the web, you should look into [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API). Much more performant and flexible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sorry but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: @SBullsy: added a jsFiddle link in my answer. Helpful?

Comment: Hey this is great! Thank you! It's not exactly what I wanted tho, I just want to leave a line trail behind, not duplicate the circle. Like just have the circle lead a path of 1px stroke.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. Can you explain what "line trail behind" means visually? You would still have to *draw* something behind the circle right? It looks like what you really want is a line drawing function, which as far as I can tell, is available in a Canvas API. Did you read my post-scriptem above? Are you aware of canvas?

Comment: I want to draw the path that the circle travels on. I am aware of the Canvas API but I don't know how to animate the line drawing by making it appear gradually behind the Circle item. I am new to this stuff so it all seems complicated to me, sorry for being a pain. Furthermore, the link you provided doesn't work right now.

Comment: There is plenty of stuff available on internet regarding Canvas. Here is my personal favourite and the one I recommend to people getting into Canvas: **[Coding Math](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zm9bqSSiIdo&index=1&list=PL7wAPgl1JVvUEb0dIygHzO4698tmcwLk9)**.